# Compute the series expansion of $\sigma(t)$ to $ O(t^3)$ in a local chart

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

i need help to solve following question.

Let $ \Phi _t$ and $\Psi _t$ be 1-parameter flows generated by smooth vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on a manifold M. For a given point $ p \in M$, define $$ \sigma(t)= \Psi_{-t} \circ \Phi_{-t}\circ\Psi_t \circ \Phi_t(p) $$

Can someone help me please to calculate it properly?

Comment: What do you mean by "properly"? Explicitly? Do you have explicit $X,Y$?

Comment: I mean only to calculate $\sigma(t)$, no i don't have explicit $X$,$Y$

Comment: Essentially you compute the derivatives of $\sigma$ using the chain rule and that $\frac{d}{dt}(\Phi_t)(p)_{|t=0} = X(p), \frac{d}{dt}(\Psi_t)(p)_{|t=0} = Y(p)$. Do you have problems applying the chain rule?